# Error in Visual Studio 2012 , SQL Server 2008R2 , Reporting

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

An error occurred during local report processing. The report definition for report 'xxx' has not been specified Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am getting this error while using VS 2012, but when I use VS 2010 it works totally fine ..

Any suggestions .. ??
The error occurs as shown in the Image below]

Comment: Show the code that is generating the error message...

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved By me  :D
 make sure the ReportViewer1’s property window, LocalReport’s Report path contains Report1.rdlc specified.